# How to use "any" in select list of a form to work in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have form which use below codes:

```
<select name="ptype">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

now, how can the php page process the "Any" field in mysql. I tried below code, but didnot worked on process page:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE ptype='{$_POST['ptype']}'");
echo mysql_error();
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

}
```

There are multiple select option which use "any", all fields run on same query. here any means all value

what may be the error ? or how to use "any" value ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `value="any"`?

Comment: Do you actually have a `ptype` in your database that has a value of "Any"?

Comment: you mean `Any` = all rows as in `ptype=1, ptyp1=2 ...` etc?

Comment: Your form elements need to be **"named"**. I.e.: `<option selected="selected" value="" name="any_name">`

Comment: @Fred - the `name` goes inside the `select` tag, not the `options`.

Comment: @DevlshOne I only gave one example. It's up to the OP to do his/her homework.

Comment: @DevlshOne *(addendum)* Then may I suggest you include that in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ptype = $_POST['ptype'];
if ($ptype == "Any") {
    $w = " WHERE 1";
} else {
    $w = " WHERE ptype = '" . $ptype . "'";
}
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `listing`" . $w);
echo mysql_error();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for it separately:

```
SELECT *
FROM `listing`
WHERE '{$_POST['ptype']}' = 'ANY' or ptype='{$_POST['ptype']}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the option is `any`, programitically change your query as :

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `listing`");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `any` means that both can work, just drop the WHERE clause from your query if `$_POST['ptype']` doesn't have a value (or give it a value and check for that).